# Single server, nginx as a reverse proxy, multiple domains/websites

Tags: nginx, proxy, domain, reverse-proxy

I have this nginx config for my website on https where nginx is used as a reverse proxy server:

```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name my_domain123.com www.my_domain123.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name localhost www.my_domain123.com;
    return 301 https://my_domain123.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
      server_name my_domain123.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:4000 https://my_domain123.com;
      # ...........................

    }
```

How should I adjust it so that I can host **multiple** websites with **different** domain names on the **same server**?
Where in the config exactly should I insert the new configuration for that new website?

Or should I create one more site-available/enabled for it also? **Yet, the question remains:** how would I combine 2 or more configurations -- same server, multiple domains -- properly?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you show in your question?

Comment: @Sven, show what?

Comment: The config excerpt in your question with multiple `server` blocks is exactly how you configure nginx to serve multiple domains - what more do you need?

Comment: @Sven, that's for a single domain. how exactly add more domains and sections/config for them?

Comment: You just have multiple `server` blocks and add all relevant configuration tsatements to them, as e.g. `listen`, `server_name` or `proxy_redirect`.  You can put them all into the same file if you like.

Comment: @Rakori How did you solved it?

Answer (score 14):

Normally you create a new config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/newserver.conf` for the new server and link it from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.
To use nginx as reverse proxy, you configure SSL in nginx (`ssl_certificate`, ...) and in the location section you use `proxy_pass` to the non SSL server at localhost. `proxy_redirect` is also needed, but that only modifies the `Location` header in case your non SSL local server sends one.
You find an example in the following [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins).

## Multiple http servers on localhost using different ports

```
server {
    server_name mydomain-01.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8001 https://mydomain-01.com;
      ...
    }
}
server {
    server_name mydomain-02.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8002 https://mydomain-02.com;
      ...
    }
}
```

## Single http server on localhost using hostname based sites

```
server {
    server_name mydomain-01.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://s1.localdomain:4000 https://mydomain-01.com;
      ...
    }
}
server {
    server_name mydomain-02.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://s2.localdomain:4000 https://mydomain-02.com;
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question

Comment: Do you have a single webserver on http://localhost:4000 serving all domains or multiple servers on different ports?

Comment: none -- one physical server, but multiple websites on different ports. one website for one domain

Comment: I can't figure out -- how can I apply your solution to my case? where are the ports? I have 3 sections per domain -- where are the sections in your answer?